# Returning value of a static methods

Tags: php, class, oop, static-methods

When I run this code

```
class Kernel
{
    private $settings = array();

    public function handle(Settings $conf)
    {
        $this->settings = $conf;
        return $this;
    }


    public function run()
    {
        var_dump($this->settings);
    }
}


class Settings
{
    public static function appConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'database' => array(
                'hostname' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'test',
                'database' => 'testdb'
            )
        );
    }
}

$kernel = new Kernel;
$kernel->handle(Settings::appConfig())->run();
```

I get error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Kernel::handle() must be an instance of Settings, array given, called in....
```

Does it mean that type hinting works only for instances but not for static methods? If now how to achieve type hinting for static methods?

Comment: `handle()` expects an object of class `Settings` but you are just providing a simple array (the return value of `appConfig()`)

Comment: the return value of appConfig is not an instance of class Settings, you cannot give an type array to a method which wants to get a type settings

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error text explains it.
You are passing an array here:

```
$kernel->handle(Settings::appConfig())->run();
```

Because your `Settings::appConfig()` method returns an array.
You have to pass an instance there.

Answer (score 0):

$conf needs to be an instance of the Settings object to prevent the error.

The handle methods class hint means that only objects instances the Settings class will be accepted. If you want to use an array with the handle method you need to make this change.

```
public function handle(Settings $conf)
```

to

```
public function handle(array $conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

this would work:

```
public function handle(array $conf)
{
    $this->settings = $conf;
    return $this;
}
```